# Creating a large dataframe out of 100 csv files (full join required)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to create a dataframe one 100+ csv file. My issues is that I have more than 100 CSVs with more than 55000 rows in each (as primary keys).

Now the difference between the csv files is that is all columns (maybe around 1200 columns) were broken into separate files. In other words, I need to do a FULL JOIN these csv files based on the PRIMARY row.

I got to the below code so far but need help to compelete it.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\user1\GCP_All')

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])

#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv(r'C:\Users\user1\GCP_All\combined.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

similar example is this:

```
CSV_A:
PK        TOP_SALES  TOP_PURCH
111111    A          B
222222    C          D
333333    E          F

CSV_B:
PK        AVG_SALE   AVG_PURCH
111111    G          H
222222    I          J
333333    K          L

CSV_C:
PK        MIN_SALE   MIN_PURCH
111111    M          N
222222    O          P
333333    Q          R


desired output:
PK    TOP_SALES  TOP_PURCH  AVG_SALE   AVG_PURCH  MIN_SALE  MIN_PURCH
111111    A          B      G          H          M         N
222222    O          P      I          J          O         P
333333    Q          R      K          L          Q         R
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Seeing some example csv would help

Comment: @CaiusJard  I've added some sample csv files to simulate the scenario. but the real files have 55K rows by 200 columns each. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `PK` column to index and then add `axis=1` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0) for f in all_filenames ], axis=1)

print (combined_csv)
       TOP_SALES TOP_PURCH AVG_SALE AVG_PURCH MIN_SALE MIN_PURCH
PK                                                              
111111         A         B        G         H        M         N
222222         C         D        I         J        O         P
333333         E         F        K         L        Q         R
```

Comment: thanks for your help but didn't work. I'm getting "ValueError: Index PK invalid" error after adding the code you added.

Comment: @SobenDevUR - Is `PK` always first column? then change solution to `combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0) for f in all_filenames ], axis=1)`

Comment: <index_col=0>  this change didn't show any errors but the outputted file is not correct. It only has 2 rows now (header + one row) while it should have more than 57K rows.

Comment: @SobenDevUR - If not working problem is in data, unfortunately :(

Comment: well I managed to make it work by working on a smaller data. however, issue is the output file doesn't have the PK column.

Comment: thank you very much for helping me out. because first column was dropped in all files when using index_col=0, I instead used index_column=None and now all first columns are showing up, however, they are all redundant because I need it only once. any ideas on this?

Comment: @SobenDevUR - `because first column was dropped` - first column was not dropped, but converted to index. So then possible use `concat`, because join by index values, so finally by foirst column converted to index.

Comment: well yes but because I can't see that PK column and it content anymore, I can't use my excel file (because primary key is not available). so is there any workaround for it? I need to keep that column which is repeating at the beginning of each file, but only once. not repeated.

Comment: @SobenDevUR - so need `combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0) for f in all_filenames ], axis=1).rename_axis('PK').reset_index()` ?

Comment: @SobenDevUR - what means `because I can't see that PK column and it content anymore` ? in input files? in `[pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0) for f in all_filenames ]` ? In `combined_csv` ? Do you try my solution with data from question? It working well

Comment: @SobenDevUR - added ouput to answer.